# Importing class in main class

Tags: java

I've created one class as below:

```
package com.ashwin;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Register {
   ...static methods
}
```

Now I've my main class and included this on the top,

```
import com.ashwin.*;

public class PersonalDictionaryDriver {
   ... main method{
       Register.loadUsers();
   }
}
```

It gives me following errors

```
PersonalDictionaryDriver.java:1: error: package com.ashwin does not exist
import com.ashwin.*;
^
PersonalDictionaryDriver.java:14: error: package com.ashwin does not exist
        com.ashwin.Register.loadUsers();
                  ^
```

Comment: classes in the same package don't need to be imported, replace `import com.ashwin.*;` with `package com.ashwin;`

Comment: Where's PersonalDictionaryDriver.java located?

Comment: All classes are in same folder.

Comment: include the path com/ashwi to the CLASSPATH